# Java one shot timer to terminate main function

Tags: java, timer

I implemented a simple timer with Observer pattern. I wanted to terminate the main function when 5 minutes passes while it is running. Basically what I need is a simple one shot timeout functionality. How can I achieve this? My code is not working. Below is the timer class

```
public class OneShotTimer  extends Observable implements Runnable{

@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        Thread.sleep(30);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        System.out.println("Exception in timer");
    }
    notifyObservers();
}
```

In main class's constructor I initialize that timer.

```
public GreenOverlayMain(){
    timer = new OneShotTimer();
    timer.addObserver(this);
    Thread t = new Thread(timer, "mythread");
    t.start();
}
```

However the update() function of main class is never executed because timeout never happens. MainClass implements Observer interface. Below is the update function.

```
@Override
public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.gc();
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Why not `java.util.Timer`?

Comment: Where do you call the said update() function?

Comment: see this link http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/java-se-api-tutorials/883-how-use-timer-java.html

Comment: Call `setChanged()` before `notifyObservers()`.

Comment: @ppeterka66 I added the update function above. Main class implements the Observer interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This example print `update` end finish execution.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    //scheduler executor is a lot more sophisticated solution
    final ScheduledExecutorService sheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    class MyO extends Observable {
        public void trackChanged(){
            setChanged(); //this method is protected in super class
        }
    };
    //must be final because it used in nested class
    final MyO o = new MyO();
    o.addObserver(new Observer() {
        @Override
        public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
            //your processing here
            System.out.println("update");
            sheduler.shutdown();
        }
    });
    sheduler.schedule(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            o.trackChanged();
            o.notifyObservers();
        }
    }, 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS); //set any timout
}
```

Comment: This solution works but I think it takes more than 3 seconds to expire and I do not know why.

Comment: @fatma.ekici of course it is take more than 3 sec, because of the overhead for scheduling. But hope it is a minimal. Try to use System.currentTimeMillis() to measure precise timeout. Any way, time dependency in application is a bad smell.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a reusable OneShotTimer.

```java
    new OneShotTimer(3, () -> setChange());
```

```java
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class OneShotTimer
{

    final ScheduledExecutorService sheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    /// Call [callback] after [duration] seconds.
    public OneShotTimer(int duration, OneShotCallback callback)
    {
        sheduler.schedule(() -> _callback(callback), duration, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    void _callback(OneShotCallback callback)
    {
        sheduler.shutdown();
        callback.callback();
    }

    public interface OneShotCallback
    {
        void callback();
    }

}
```